# Facebook still shows small thumbnail with og meta tags in place

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

I have a page on my website that is located at domain.com/mypage.html

I would like to do a link share with this link so that the ad is displayed but the whole image is still a link to our actual web page. The problem is that Facebook will still display the image in a small thumbnail like before they added the new larger link shares last year.

I have added all the og meta tags for the image, I have made sure the image has an aspect ratio of 1.91:1 with an actual size of 1200x627. The titles and description tags all have very little text so they are within the character limit.

I have refreshed the Facebook crawler's copy of the page with the Facebook Debugger/Linter tool.

Nothing I do changes how Facebook will display this link-share. It will never display in the larger format.

Here are meta-tags in mypage.html:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.domain.com/images/fb_ad.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="627" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.domain.com/mypage.html"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="My Description"/>
```